# Webassembly project referencing two other webassembly projects: Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type

Tags: blazor-webassembly, multi-project

I created three webassembly project in one solution, one of them referencing the other two.
BlazorUI2 that references Client1 and Client2.

So I separate their assets like this, In Client1.csproj:

```
<StaticWebAssetBasePath>Client1</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
```

and

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot1\service-worker.published.js" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

And Client2 config is like Client1.

But I get the error:

```
MSB4094 "C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorUI2 - Copy\Client1\obj\Debug\net8.0\service-worker
\service-worker.js;C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorUI2 - Copy\Client2\obj\Debug\net8.0\service-
worker\service-worker.js;C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorUI2 - Copy\BlazorUI2\obj\Debug\net8.0
\service-worker\service-worker.js" is an invalid value for the "File" parameter of the 
"WriteLinesToFile" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type 
"Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".  BlazorUI2   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100
\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets
\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets    159
```

Based on an answer in StackOverFlow I changed .Net SDK webassembly manifest from:

```
<WriteLinesToFile
  File="@(_BuildServiceWorkerFile->'%(Identity)')"
  Lines="/*Manifest version: $(_BuildServiceWorkerAssetsManifestVersion)*/"
  Condition="'$(_BuildServiceWorkerAssetsManifestVersion)' != ''" />
```

to:

```
<WriteLinesToFile
        File="%(AssemblyInfoFiles.FullPath)"
        Lines="AssemblyInformationalVersion(&quot;$(LabelName)&quot;)]"
        Overwrite="false"/>
```

but I get the error:

```
Error   MSB4044 The "WriteLinesToFile" task was not given a value for the required 
parameter "File".   Client1 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100
\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets
\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets    163
```

So how to correct this?

EDIT:

Batching files also is not working the same error raised:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <AssemblyInfoFiles Include="$(SolutionRoot)\**\*assemblyinfo.cs" />
 </ItemGroup>
```